# BluetoothLE startAdvertising: settings changes without effect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing a Cordova plugin to use the new [Android BluetoothLE API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/package-summary.html) introduced with API 21 within my Ionic App. Everything works fine so far. I can scan for devices and I can also successfully start advertising via BLE.

For advertising I call `startAdvertising` and pass the corresponding `AdvertiseSettings` which I converted from a JSONObject. The problem is, once I started advertising with those settings, I cannot start advertising with different settings afterwards. **In other words, `startAdvertising` will always use the first `AdvertiseSettings` it received.** The settings will even remain, when I recompile my App and update it on the device. A reset of the settings is only possible by disabling and enabling Bluetooth. But this is not really what I wanna do every time.

Here is, how I start advertising in the code:

```
// ... check if advertising is supported 

// start advertising in new thread
cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        AdvertiseSettings advertiseSettings = getAdvertiseSettings(settingsJSON);
        AdvertiseData advertiseData = getAdvertiseData(advertiseDataJSON);
        AdvertiseCallback advertiseCallback = getAdvertiseCallback();

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "'startAdvertising' settings before call: "+advertiseSettings.toString() );

        bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, advertiseData, advertiseCallback);
    }
});
```

As you can see I log the passed `advertiseSettings` to logcat. To double-check, which settings are in effect, I also log them when `onStartSuccess` is called:

```
advertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        advertising = true;

        // ... some output to the JavaScript interface

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "'startAdvertising' result: " + settingsInEffect.toString() );

    }
    // ... onStartFailure
}
```

And this is the output when I try to start advertising with varying timeouts:

```
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): initializing BleAdvertising plugin...
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'disableBluetooth' result: true
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'enableBluetooth' result: true
W/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' settings before call: Settings [mAdvertiseMode=1, mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel=2, mAdvertiseConnectable=false, mAdvertiseTimeoutMillis=5000]
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' result: Settings [mAdvertiseMode=1, mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel=2, mAdvertiseConnectable=false, mAdvertiseTimeoutMillis=5000]
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' result: Stopped advertising after specified time.
W/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' settings before call: Settings [mAdvertiseMode=1, mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel=2, mAdvertiseConnectable=false, mAdvertiseTimeoutMillis=6000]
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' result: Settings [mAdvertiseMode=1, mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel=2, mAdvertiseConnectable=false, mAdvertiseTimeoutMillis=5000]
I/BleAdvertising_Plugin(19094): 'startAdvertising' result: Stopped advertising after specified time.
```

After I restarted Bluetooth I have set the settings with `mAdvertiseTimeoutMillis=5000` and the log of `settingsInEffect` returned the value 5000, which is as expected. But then I set new settings with a timeout of 6000, while the `settingsInEffect` still have 5000. The latter is also, what is indeed done by the device (Nexus 9, Android 5.0.1) - it stops advertising after 5000ms not 6000ms.

**Am I doing something wrong here? Is this a bug? Or actually how Android manages Advertising?**

I want to open source this plugin as soon as everything works and I will mention everyone who helps me. Thanks!

Comment: a) Thank you for doing this work; am looking forward to the result. Don't have a BluetoothLE peripheral capable device myself yet, or I'd volunteer to help debug.
b) Any chance that there's just something basically wrong with how you are trying to change the settings and that, rather than call 1 succeeding and call 2 failing, both calls are failing so you're just getting default values? Permissions maybe? You don't show any errors but the api docs do have the note: "Most of the methods here require BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission"

Comment: Thanks @agunn for your motivating comment :)

Comment: I think it's not a problem of permissions. I do have both, the BLUETOOTH and the  BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions, set in my manifest. Without those permissions in effect, startAdvertising should not work at all. But it does - only without the possibility to change the first settings provided. Which also means, your custom settings will be in effect, not any default ones. I can always change the settings by restarting the BluetoothAdapter. But this is not what I wanna do every time :(

Comment: Hi @RobYed. Have you managed to solve this problem? I am having the same issue on Android 7.1.1 device...